# How can you display screen size in Android Studio(simple way)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-displaymanager

I'm trying to display the screen width and height to logcat.

I have seen this stack overflow post: [Getting screen width on API Level 30 (Android 11): getDefaultDisplay() and getMetrics() are now deprecated. What should we use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63407883/getting-screen-width-on-api-level-30-android-11-getdefaultdisplay-and-getme)

But the accepted solution is confusing and complicated for someone like me new to `DisplayMetrics` and `Display` in Android Studio.

Currently, I know how to do it this way:

```
public class ScreenUtility {
    private Activity activity;
    private Float dpHeight, dpWidth;

    public ScreenUtility(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        float density = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / density;
        dpHeight = displayMetrics.widthPixels / density;

    }


    public Float getDpHeight() {
        return dpHeight;
    }

    public Float getDpWidth() {
        return dpWidth;
    }
}
```

However, `.getMetrics` is deprecated. As a result, the code returns the width and heigh as `null`.

1. (I am watching an older video on these concepts)**Is there any way I can change this code and adjust my knowledge to the modern methods of `Display` and `DisplayMetrics`?**
2. **How are `DisplayMetrics` and `Display` different? In the docs, it describes them as both tools that provide the size of a Display. Or is `DisplayMetrics` used as a parameter for `Display`?**

Thanks!!

Comment: do you want explanation for the accepted solution of the question you are referring to?

Comment: Hi, my question is this: How are DisplayMetrics and Display different? In the docs, it describes them as both tools that provide the size of a Display. Or is DisplayMetrics used as a parameter for Display? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can display height and width of the screen

```
try{
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    Log.e("test","Height : " + height + " width : " + width);
}
catch(Exception e){
Log.e("test","exception : " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. You cannot call getWindowManager like that though, the IDE throws an error.

Comment: ya ok then wrap them with try catch

Comment: that's not the problem, you can't call getWindowManager, you have to set it to a display and call activity.getWindowManager(which is what I already did).

Answer (score 0):

```
val windowMetrics = requireActivity().windowManager.currentWindowMetrics
val displayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics

val pxHeight = windowMetrics.bounds.height()
val pxWidth  = windowMetrics.bounds.width()

val density  = displayMetrics.density

val dpHeight = pxHeight/density
val dpWidth  = pxWidth/density
```